# Size of camera representation

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have two cameras in my project but they are shown differently (one is represented bigger than the other), although they have the same focal length and the same sensor size (and the same scale). Are there any other properties that are considered when drawing the camera representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Size property under Display category in the Camera tab in the Properties Editor is precisely for that - the size of the camera displayed in the viewport.

[image]

Comment: Good! Thanks. I do not have the "m" after the size and I am not sure what are the units (I had 0.5 in one camera properties and 1.0 in the other camera properties).

Comment: There are no units then. You can set them in the scene properties. There is some really nice functionality in Blender's input fields if units are set to something. Say if you work in meters, but you have some measurements in any other units like inches for example. You can then just write them in inches ending with 'in' and they will be converted automatically. I find it extremely useful. Even with modal operators like grab when inputting numerical values during the operation it's possible after you hit Numpad *. It doesn't work with units not set.

Comment: However, what are the "size" referring to? If I put 1.0m the camera happens to by long about 0.9m.

Comment: It refers to the units set, If it's meters than it is meters, if it is not set, then it is 'a unit'. I think it is weirdly a 'radius' of the camera object displayed - a half of the length across the longer dimension. It makes little sense if you think about it probably, but it is not something that matters a lot...

Comment: unfortunately this has a maximum size of 1 km :(

Comment: @endolith I think it really does not make any sense at all to have it that big in normal circumstances.  If you need the camera size to be that big and work with 1 unit set to 1 meter, you are definitely doing something wrong. Set the scale of the units in the scene properties if you are "filming"  planets or something like that and need to see the camera, you can have it any logical size if you scale your units logically: https://i.imgur.com/zY8SrFF.png

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Oh, ok.  I'm just starting to use Blender and trying to make planet-size models and running into problems like this.  :)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Hmm "This only influences the values displayed in the user interface and not how things behave internally. For example, physics simulations don’t take the unit scale into account."

Comment: Is there a difference in physics simulations when units are uniformly scaled? I don't think there is... I imagined you might only need to change the default values to match the unit scale if needed. I don't do much planet sized simulations and I am no expert in physics though so this might be a good new question to ask...